# Dynamic Node creation in ROS feurte

Tags: nodes, ros

I'm trying to spawn and destroy nodes using code during run time.  I know that ROS groovy has `rosspawn` but the project I'm working on is in feurte.  This is the code I have for a node class

```
class node {
    private:
        ros::NodeHandle *n;
    public:
        void init(int argc, char **argv, std::string s) {
            ros::init(argc, argv, s);
            n = new NodeHandle();
        }
        void shutdown() {
            n->~NodeHandle();
        }
};
```

I've tested it using `rosnode list` and it seems to work.  My question is, Is this bad programming or is there an unforeseen error that can occur?  The questions I've seen questions posted say that a system call is needed in order to spawn a node during execution.

Answer (score 0):

It is fine to do it this way if you're just trying to dynamically create a single node.  If you want to create multiple nodes you will need to create separate processes, necessitating a system call.